# Pandas how to checkif substring of one column is a substring of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a input like this, and I want to check where a substring in `col_1` exists in `col_2` or not. What I wanted to try contains two step: split text from `col_1` and then use for loop to do the comparison with `col_2`. I'm wondering if I can achieve this via `df.apply` ?

INPUT>

```
dct = {'col_1': ['X_a', 'Y_b'],
       'col_2': ['a_b_c', 'c_d_e',]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

EXPECT RESULT>

```
  col_1  col_2  result
0   X_a  a_b_c   True
1   Y_b  c_d_e   False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something involving set intersections?

```
df['result'] = (
  df['col_1'].str.split('_').map(set) & df['col_2'].str.split('_').map(set))
df

  col_1  col_2  result
0   X_a  a_b_c    True
1   Y_b  c_d_e   False
```

Comment: thanks! Your answer is helpful but also remind me that my case is for more than two strings concatenate together..!  But still list comprehensions is definitely elegant...hmmm

Comment: @lamiren how does my update work?

Comment: Elegant and works for me!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use *`df.apply`* with *`axis=1`*. [This mean that it will apply *function* to each row](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> dct = {'col_1': ['X_a', 'Y_b'],
...        'col_2': ['a', 'c',]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
>>>
>>> def check_substring(row):
...     _, second = row.col_1.split("_")
...     return second in row.col_2
...
>>> df["result"] = df.apply(check_substring, axis=1)
>>> print(df)
  col_1 col_2  result
0   X_a     a    True
1   Y_b     c   False
```

Comment: thanks! Your answer is helpful but also remind me that my case is for more than two strings concatenate together..!

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner using apply and an inner loop.

```
df['result'] =  df.apply(lambda x: any(y in x['col_1'] for y in x['col_2'].split('_')), axis=1)
```

**Exmaple**

```
dct = {'col_1': ['X_a', 'Y_b'],
       'col_2': ['a_b_c', 'c_d_e',]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

df['result'] =  df.apply(lambda x: any(y in x['col_1'] for y in x['col_2'].split('_')), axis=1)
>>> df
  col_1  col_2  result
0   X_a  a_b_c    True
1   Y_b  c_d_e   False
```

Comment: this method also works for me!! I didn't come up with usage with any

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['result'] = np.nan
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['result'][i] = df['col_2'][i] in list(df['col_1'][i])
```